# Spring boot / docker / nginx - query param encoding

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rest, nginx, encoding

I have **spring boot application** (3.0.9) that expose rest service that get string as query param.
The application is deployed by **docker** image that include the jar.
In front of the container, There is **nginx** server as load balancer.

When I send request directly to the docker, with encoding parameter (for empty string) - everything works fine. example:
http://11.11.11.11:8080/test/% 22% 22
When I send the request to the nginx, I get error 400. example: http://22.22.22.22/test/test/% 22% 22.
When I send the request to nginx with other string parameter - works fine. example: http://22.22.22.22/test/test/string.
(The spaces in the URL is just to avoid stackoverflow to display it as ")
The spring rest class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", consumes = {MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
public interface Test {

   @GetMapping(path = "/{params}")
   ListResult getList(@PathVariable(name="params", required = false) String... params);

}
```

The docker image:

```
FROM ubi8/openjdk-17-runtime
WORKDIR /work
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./target/app.jar  ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -jar ./app.jar" ]
```

The nginx configuration:

```
upstream test {

  server  11.11.11.11:8080;

}

location /test/ {

   proxy_pass "http://test/";

}
```

**NGINX should encode the query parameters as default. So, what is wrong?**

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me you are sending the request to "/test/test/" expecting nginx to remove one of the path prefixes because it is proxy passing but that is not how it works. You should make the exact same request you did to the spring container.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When I send the request to nginx with other string parameter it works fine. so, i assume the location definition is ok. I edited the post to add this detail.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear, you expected nginx pass the params in the original format (url encoded) or already decoded to spring?

Comment: I expected  nginx to pass the params as it sent (encode).

Comment: I found this log in the docker container: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 27: http://localhost:8080/test/"". it look like nginx send " insteadof %22

Comment: I have tested this with nodejs and nginx send the original path. I have no idea what spring is doing but the problem could be there, no?